Why does Telemachus hang the women instead of following Odysseus' instructions?
In The Odyssey, after Odysseus has slain the suitors, he tells Telemachus to have the disloyal women help to clean up the mess, and then to cut them to pieces:

“These dead must be disposed of first of all.
Direct the women. Tables and chairs will be
scrubbed with sponges, rinsed and rinsed again.
When our great room is fresh and put in order,
take them outside, these women,
between the roundhouse and the palisade,
and hack them with your swordblades till you cut
the life out of them, and every thought of sweet
Aphroditê under the rutting suitors,
when they lay down in secret.”
The Odyssey, chapter 22, translation by Robert Fitzgerald (1961), lines 454–463

However, after they've done the grisly work of cleaning up the suitors' bodies, Telemachus does not follow Odysseus' instructions, but instead has them hanged:

Telémakhos, who knew his mind, said curtly:
“I would not give the clean death of a beast
to trulls who made a mockery of my mother
and of me too—you sluts, who lay with suitors.”
He tied one end of a hawser to a pillar
and passed the other about the roundhouse top,
taking the slack up, so that no one’s toes
could touch the ground. They would be hung like doves
or larks in springes triggered in a thicket,
where the birds think to rest—a cruel nesting.
So now in turn each woman thrust her head
into a noose and swung, yanked high in air,
to perish there most piteously.
Their feet danced for a little, but not long.
479–492

Why does Telemachus decide to hang them instead? Why does he say he won't give them the "clean death of a beast"? What's the difference between hacking them to pieces with a sword and hanging them?
Why does Telemachus depart from Odysseus' instructions and hang the women instead of cutting them to pieces?

The explanation given by Telemachus at 22.462–464 is that death by the sword is καθαρός (“clean, spotless”), and this is too good for the women who rebuked Telemachus and Penelope and had sex with the suitors. Hanging, he implies, is a more appropriate death.

There is little information available for the status of hanging in archaic times, but in Classical Athens and thereafter it was clearly a dishonorable means of death.
Laurel Fulkerson (2002). ‘Epic Ways of Killing a Woman: Gender and Transgression in Odyssey 22.465–72’. The Classical Journal 97:4, pages 341–342.

In Classical tragedy (that is, in the 5th century BCE), death by the sword is honourable, while death by hanging is dishonourable. This is stated explicitly by Helen in Euripides’ play:

Helen To hang oneself, high in the air, is unseemly, even slaves consider it undignified; but to stab oneself is noble and good, and the moment of rending life from the body is short.
Euripides (412 BCE) Helen 299–302. Translated by E. P. Coleridge (1938). Perseus Digital Library.

In other cases, the connection is not quite so explicit, but when a character suffers shame or dishonour and then hangs herself, the mode of suicide can be interpreted as the character’s fatal expression of her shame, as well as the playwright’s comment on it.
In Euripides’ Helen, we are told that Helen’s mother Leda has hanged herself out of shame at her daughter’s elopement with Paris:

Helen My mother is no more; through shame of my disgraceful marriage she tied a noose around her neck.
Helen 686–687.

In Sophocles’ Oedipus Tyrannus, Jocasta hangs herself in shame at having married her own son (“There we beheld the woman hanging by the neck in a twisted noose of swinging cords”, line 1264); in the same playwright’s Antigone, the heroine hangs herself after Cleon dishonours her brother Polyneices by refusing him burial (“in the furthest part of the tomb we saw her hanging by the neck, fastened by a halter of fine linen threads”, line 1220), and in Euripides’ Hippolytus, Phaidra hangs herself “feeling shame at her bitter fate” (line 771).
Perhaps death by the sword was seen as courageous because it occurred in battle, and death by hanging was seen as dishonourable because it was a method of suicide, which was abominated. For example, Plato says that, under his ideal code of laws, the tombs of suicides “shall be, first, in an isolated position with not even one adjacent, and, secondly, they shall be buried in those borders of the twelve districts which are barren and nameless, without note, and with neither headstone nor name to indicate the tombs” (Laws 9.873).

Suicide, then, could be the tragic death chosen under the weight of necessity by those on whom fell “the intolerable pain of a misfortune from which there is no way out.”† But in tragedy itself it was mainly a woman’s death. There was one form of suicide—an already despised form of death—that was more disgraceful and associated more than any other with irremediable dishonor. This was hanging, a hideous death, or more exactly a “formless” death (ἀσχήμων), the extreme of defilement that one inflicted on oneself only in the utmost shame.
Nicole Loraux (1987). Tragic Ways of Killing a Woman, page 9. Harvard University Press.
† Plato (c. 350 BCE), Laws 9.873.

I think there is one case in Classical tragedy where a man is threatened with hanging, and that is in Eumenides where Orestes says that, depending on the outcome of his trial for the murder of Clytemnestra, “I will meet my end by hanging, or I will live” (line 746). Here the hanging of a convicted murderer would be an expression of the community’s abhorrence of his deed.
By contrast, when men get the choice of how to end their life, they choose other means: Ajax throws himself onto his sword, Haemon drives his sword into his side, and Heracles burns himself alive on his funeral pyre.
This interpretation of Telemachus’s speech at 22.462–464 seems straightforward. However, some scholars are skeptical:

καθαρός is in an emphatic position; its meaning, however, is not quite certain. None of the other eight Homeric examples of the word authorize us to interpret it in the religious sense which it later acquired; in 4.750, 4.759, 6.61, 17.48, 17.58 it refers merely to clean clothing, in Iliad 8.491, 10.199, 23.61 to a clear and unencumbered space. Nor can Telemachus mean a ‘clean’ death in the sense of one free from ritual pollution, since the spilling of blood by decapitation would in turn require further purification. Furthermore, the fact that so many tragic heroes choose to commit suicide by hanging themselves† excludes the possibility that he means an ‘honourable and heroic’ death by the sword, as against a shameful and dirty death by the rope. We are left with the idea of a ‘clean’, in the sense of ‘quick and easy’, death. Be that as it may, the speech is out of character for the mild Telemachus, and Odysseus’ easy acceptance of the change in plan is surprising.
Manuel Fernández-Galiano (1992). Note on Odyssey 22.462. In Joseph Russo, Manuel Fernández-Galiano, and Alfred Heubeck, editors (1992). A Commentary on Homer’s Odyssey, volume 3, page 300. Oxford: Clarendon.
† If Fernández-Galiano meant “heroes” to include women, then he’s right that there are lots of examples, but the discussion above indicates that hanging was a shameful end in these cases. If he only included men, then I am not so sure. There is Iphis in book 14 of Ovid’s Metamorphoses, but who else?

Having rejected the straightforward explanation, one needs to be prepared to consider other ideas:

There is a useful discussion of the minutiae of the execution in the paper by Fernand Robert, ‘Le Supplice d’Antigone et celui des servantes d’Ulysse’, Bulletin de Correspondance Hellénique 70 (1946), 501–5, though its bold general thesis may not convince: it proposes that the whole passage is an interpolation intended to provide an αἴτιον† for an ancient myth similar to that of Antigone’s hanging in a θόλος or beehive tomb, in which both aspects of the punishment would be related to the killing of a scapegoat, φαρμακός, designed to cleanse the miasma of a crime; the suspended corpses would, in this theory, recall the oscilla‡ of Vergil’s Georgics 2.389, which were hung from trees to ensure fertility; and the women-slaves themselves would be a distant memory of ancient rituals, since Autonoe and Eurynome (18.182, 17.495, though both, to be sure, belong to the number of the innocent maidservants) bear the same names§ as a goddess worshipped in a θόλος at Mantinea (Pausanias 8.9.5) and a seagoddess mentioned in Iliad 18.398 who had a sanctuary in Arcadia (Pausanias 8.41.4).
Fernández-Galiano, note on Odyssey 441–473.
† Cause, origin. ‡ Masks of Bacchus. § The goddess named by Pausanias at 8.9.5 is Antinoe, not Autonoe.

However, a supposed interpolation from some otherwise unrecorded myth or ritual is a common resort when a passage is hard to explain or the purpose of a story is obscure, so we ought to be at least as skeptical of this theory as we are of the other.
